# Cleaning up inactive user records in aiogram 3 using MemoryStorage

Tags: python, aiogram

I need help solving a task. I have a bot on aiogram 3 that uses FSM with MemoryStorage. I need to clear records of users who haven't used the bot for more than a day (to avoid cluttering memory).

In the handlers, the variable last_activity is updated in the state with datetime.datetime.now() every time the bot is used. The idea is to check all user states from dp.storage.storage once in a specific interval (say, every hour). If the last_activity of a user is more than current_time - timedelta(days=1), the record should be deleted from MemoryStorage.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to work with MemoryStorage: extracting current_time for each user and deleting the record if it meets the condition.

Ideally, I would like to continue using MemoryStorage to store states at the moment.